# Ocean looks real close, but plasticy and undetailed when far. Can't find setting for this

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, ocean-simulation

I re-asked this question and added all necessary files and images, so its more clear what my problem is: now u can download the textures and blend file and render and see what i'm talking about :)

I followed this tutorial here: [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwJrb3vjAaA)

When zoomed closer to the ocean, it looks great but as soon as i zoom out wide, (what i want to do for a clip i need for my bachelors exam, it looks plasticy suddenly, it loses detail and looks horibly undetailed. like an 90's cgi scene.

I want the sun reflections on the ocean but it looks way off when zoomed out.

Download Blend file: [Ocean blend file](https://pasteall.org/media/d/5/d5cf315f47b3ad37c11fb6231dd17378.blend)

Download Ocean displacement textures: [Ocean texture files](https://we.tl/t-HTlKmvBla9)

All ocean displacement renders,for the entire animation duration are uploaded at wetransfe.

Can someone please help me and explain why this happens?

Closeup
[image: Ocean when closeup]

Wide
[image: Ocean when zoomed out]

Comment: maybe add some noise in the material etc?

Comment: The thing is, i want to use real life numbers, so my camera is like 2km above the ocean surface, i have this sun - world hdri -  from the tutorial and i want to move a plane through the shot, so in reality, u would see detailed waves and shimmer from the suns reflection, but it just looks flat, how big and where would i have to add the noise then?

Comment: I have never been in this situation but I wouldn't be suprised if a calm ocean looked like this from 2km in the sky with the sun this close to the horizon.